# How do I "update my packagelist using package manager" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, kivy

I'm following [this guide](http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) on installing Kivy. Step 2 is

> 2. Update your packagelist using your package manager

I'm very new to Ubuntu/Linux and don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've already opened a terminal, with a simple command

```
sudo apt-get update
```

That's always necessary if you have done something like:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
```

---

From `man apt-get`

```
update
    update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their
    sources. The indexes of available packages are fetched from the
    location(s) specified in /etc/apt/sources.list. For example, when 
    using a Debian archive, this command retrieves and scans the 
    Packages.gz files, so that information about new and updated packages
    is available. An update should always be performed before an upgrade
    or dist-upgrade. Please be aware that the overall progress meter will
    be incorrect as the size of the package files cannot be known in 
    advance.
```